# Css absolute div under absolut div same class

Tags: css, position

I woul like to show a list of comments and for each comment its list of comments and so on:

here is my HTML code:

```
<div class='comment'>
    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un commentaire statique</div>
    <div class='content'>
        Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto 
    </div>
    <div class='subComments'>
        <div class='comment'>
            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique</div>
            <div class='content'>
                Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem videri decuerat, ad praetorium cum pompa sollemni perrexit morbosque diu causatus nec regiam introiit nec processit in publicum, sed abditus multa in eius 
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>  


<div class='comment'>
    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un commentaire statique</div>
    <div class='content'>
        Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem viderncipem
    </div>      
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.comment{
    //border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 580px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 50px; 
}

.titre{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: blue;
    padding: 12px;
}

.content{
    padding: 12px;
}

.subComments{
    border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 580px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is what I wanna get:

[image]

And here is what I'm getting:

[image]

Now I get the two comments superimposed!!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the position of the second, third comment is dependent on the size of the previous comments  , then you DO NOT want absolute positioning

Comment: It doesn't depend on the size!
I use the absolute positioning to make indentation for the sub comments

Comment: You do not need position absolute to indent text.. just use margins/paddings

Comment: Yeas that's exactly what Im doing, if u look at my css!
when put position relative the padding doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it will works as your image, i chaged the border to border-top and position:absolut to float:left

html

```
<div class='limit'>
<div class='comment'>
<div class='titre'>Titre d'un commentaire statique</div>
<div class='content'>
Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis,     contempto 
</div>
<div class='subComments'>
<div class='comment'>
    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique</div>
    <div class='content'>
        Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem videri decuerat, ad praetorium cum pompa sollemni perrexit morbosque diu causatus nec regiam introiit nec processit in publicum, sed abditus multa in eius 
    </div>

</div>
</div>
 </div>  
<div class='comment'>
<div class='titre'>Titre d'un commentaire statique</div>
<div class='content'>
Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto Caesare, quem viderncipem
</div>      
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
<style>
.limit{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:650px;
 }
 .comment{
 //border: solid 1px blue;
 width: 580px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 float:left;
 padding-left: 50px; 
 }

 .titre{
font-size: 1.2em;
color: blue;
padding: 12px;
 }

 .content{
padding: 12px;
 }
.subComments{
border-top: solid 3px blue;
width: 580px;
float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Plz look at the images I just added, I may haven't been clear. ur code is not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Ok I modofied ur code just a little bit and it works :) thanks!

Comment: i changed it border to border-top and works fine here :) good look